# Given premise ~(P↔Q) how can one derive (~P↔Q) using Fitch?

Tags: logic, fitch

Given premise ~(P↔Q) derive (~P↔Q) using Fitch-style natural deduction. I thought of simplifying the premise but I am still not able to find an answer. Can someone please help me?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2301286/logic-proving-a-%E2%86%94-b-and-a-%E2%86%94-b-are-equivalent-in-lpls-fitch

Comment: @virmaior I wasn't able to construct a natural deduction proof using the link you mentioned, but I did provide an alternate answer there using the technique I used below: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3300974/312852 The questions are similar but the one on Math SE is looking for an equivalence proof.

Answer (score 2):

One way to approach this is to think of the goal, *¬P ↔ Q*, not as a biconditional but as this conjunction of disjunctions: *(P ∨ Q) ∧ (¬P ∨ ¬Q)*.  This will allow one to access more inference rules. Then the first step would be to assume the negation of that to derive a contradiction with the premise. (See lines 2-27 below.) Once this contradiction is obtained one can derive the desired biconditional.

Here is how this looks in the *forallx* proof checker. The proof checker you are using may look different but a similar approach should work.

[image]

Details of the inference rules and the proof checker are linked below.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Fall 2019. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf

Comment: I'm pretty sure Fitch does not have DeMorgan's rule. Without which it's going to be brutal to slog through this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a skeleton to start you out

```
 |_ ~(P ↔ Q)       Premise
 |  |_ P           Assume
 |  |  |_ Q        Assume
 |  |  |  |_ P     Assume
 |  |  |  |  Q     Reit
 |  |  |  P → Q    Cond. Intro.
 |  |  |  |_ ...   Assume
 |  |  |  |  ...   ...
 |  |  |  ...      ...
 |  |  |  ...      ...
 |  |  |  ┴        Neg. Elim.
 |  |  ~Q          Neg. Intro
 |  P → ~Q         Cond. Intro.
 |  |_ ~Q          Assume
 |  |  |_ ~P       Assume
 |  |  |  |_ ...   Assume
 |  |  |  |  ┴     Neg.Elim.
 |  |  |  |  ...   Ex Falso Quodlibet
 |  |  |  ...      ...
 |  |  |  |_ ...   ...
 |  |  |  |  ...   ...
 |  |  |  |  ...   ...
 |  |  |  ...      ...
 |  |  |  ...      ...
 |  |  |  ┴        Neg. Elim.
 |  |  ~~P         Neg. Intro.
 |  |  P           Double Neg. Elim.
 |  ~Q → P         Cond. Intro.
 |  P ↔ ~Q         Bicond. Intro.
```